# Android RecyclerView onBindViewHolder Called Twice (first time when adapter created)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have simple RecyclerViewAdapter class:

```
class TariffsCardAdapter(context: Context, tariffCardItems: List<ItemsItem?>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

   private var context: Context? = null
   private var tariffCardItems: ArrayList<ItemsItem?>? = null

    init {
      this.context=context
      this.tariffCardItems=tariffCardItems as ArrayList<ItemsItem?>
    }

   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_tariff_card_items, parent, false)
       return TariffsCardAdapterViewHolder(view)
   }

   override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return tariffCardItems!!.size
   }//getItemCount ends

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

     val viewHolder = holder as TariffsCardAdapterViewHolder
     Log.e("posX","pos:::".plus(position))
   }

   private inner class TariffsCardAdapterViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      var text: TextView? = null
      constructor(row: View) : super(row) {
         text= row.findViewById(R.id.text) as TextView
      }
   }
}
```

Now lets suppose that my `tariffCardItems: List<ItemsItem?>` will have only 5 items in the list that I want to show.

The problem is that when the adapter gets instantiated that is for the first time the `onBindViewHolder` method is called **twice**.

So that the Log values prints as:

pos:::0

pos:::1

pos:::0

pos:::1

Which means that my recycler view position will be `1` in the end.
And the very first view will be created with list item at index `1` which is wrong and should be `0.

In other words, the very first child of the recycler view is created by 1 position value which is wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. "the very first child of the recycler view is created by 1 position value which is wrong" – Nope, the first position is 0. I'm not sure why you think it's 1, but`RecyclerView` will call some `Adapter` methods an indeterminate number of times, in no guaranteed order, while it's setting itself up. You shouldn't be using that as any kind of indexing.

Comment: Yes, recyclerView may call bind methods in a non-deterministic way. I don't understand, why it is a problem. @Java Nerd Can you elaborate more on that?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because you are calling adapter 2 in code an recyclerview's bindviewholder should use to bind data not to call viewholder.

```
class TariffsCardAdapter(context: Context, tariffCardItems: List<ItemsItem?>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

   private var context: Context? = null
   private var tariffCardItems: ArrayList<ItemsItem?>? = null

    init {
      this.context=context
      this.tariffCardItems=tariffCardItems as ArrayList<ItemsItem?>
    }

   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_tariff_card_items, parent, false)
       return TariffsCardAdapterViewHolder(view)
   }

   override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return tariffCardItems!!.size
   }//getItemCount ends

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

                //bind data
   }

   private inner class TariffsCardAdapterViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      var text: TextView? = null
      constructor(row: View) : super(row) {
         text= row.findViewById(R.id.text) as TextView
      }
   }
}
```

For example your adapter should be like this

```
class CustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<User>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    //this method is returning the view for each item in the list
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    //this method is binding the data on the list
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(userList[position])
    }

    //this method is giving the size of the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    //the class is hodling the list view
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItems(user: User) {
            val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername) as TextView
            val textViewAddress  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress) as TextView
            textViewName.text = user.name
            textViewAddress.text = user.address
        }
    }
}
```

This method from your code is calling twice

```
 val viewHolder = holder as TariffsCardAdapterViewHolder
     Log.e("posX","pos:::".plus(position))
```

Comment: I want to get a user at position from the model in that how can i do that?

Comment: the problem is, i have to get the items from my list and then bind the items to the ui

Comment: Simply casting and assigning a method parameter is not causing that method to be called an unexpected number of times. This doesn't really make any sense.